# Merging two datasets in R

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 datasets companies and rounds2. Companies has 66368 rows and 10 columns
Rounds 2 has 114949 rows and 6 columns. When I merge these 2 datasets I am getting zero rows and 15 columns. Why am I getting Zero rows.

```
master_frame<-merge(rounds2,companies,by.x = c("company_permalink"),by.y = c("permalink"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZgen.png)

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
 master_frame<-merge(rounds2,companies,by.x = "company_permalink",by.y = "permalink",all=T)
```

Why don't you try renaming the common column to say 'ID'and try

```
master_frame<-merge(rounds2,companies,by = 'ID' , all=T)
```

`all.x` , `all.y` or `all` arguments are also important basis what kind of join are you looking at .